# How do I add an image from another folder when my HTML file is in a different folder?

Tags: html

For some reason, the image appears when I open it in notepad, but it doesn't work when I open my HTML file in VSCode. Adding the image in the folder of my HTML file and setting the source seems to work, but I don't want to do that.
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the path in the html tag to wherever you need:

```html
<img src="../OTHER_FOLDER/IMAGE_NAME.png" />
```

The `..` lets you move up one folder in the systems file hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is located in the folder one level up from the folder in which is index.html you can use

```
<img src="../image.jpg">
```

Else you can use absolute path:

````
<img src="C:\Users\your_user\picture.jpg"```
````

Answer (score 0):

use **../** with **src=""**
like this

```
<img src="../pictures/pic.png" alt="Image 01">
<img src="../../pictures/pic.png" alt="Image 01">
```